# Assign another value to memoized one in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have following methods

```
  const filteredTableData = useMemo(() => {
    const dataToParse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data || []))

    if (globalFilter?.length && isSearcheable) {
      return (dataToParse as OptRow[]).filter(item => {
        return Object.values(item).some(value => String(value).toLowerCase().includes(globalFilter.toLowerCase()))
      })
    }

    return dataToParse
  }, [data, globalFilter, isSearcheable])

  const checkedTableData = useCheckTableData(filteredTableData, gridRef)

  if (!!checkedTableData.differences) {
    console.log('>> save from excel')
    console.log('>> differences', checkedTableData.differences)
    console.log('>> actual', checkedTableData.actualTableData)
    handleChange(checkedTableData.differences)


    
    // gridRef.current?.gridInst.resetData(filteredTableData)
    // setFocusedCell(undefined)
  }
```

After ***handleChange*** I want to set ***filteredTableData*** to be equal with ***checkedTableData.differences***, in order to avoid calling handleChange multiple times at once.

The custom hook used to get differences and actual value is

```
export interface ICheckTableData {
  differences?: OptRow[]
  actualTableData?: OptRow[]
}

export function useCheckTableData(initialTableData: OptRow[], gridRef: MutableRefObject<any>): ICheckTableData {
  const initialTableValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialTableData))
  const actualTableData = []
  const differences = []
  const keysToIgnore = ['_', '@', 'uniqueKey', 'rowSpanMap', 'rowKey', 'sortKey']

  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < initialTableData?.length; rowIndex++) {
    const row = gridRef.current?.gridInst.getRow(rowIndex)
    if (row) {
      actualTableData.push(row)
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < actualTableData.length; i++) {
    const initialObj = initialTableValue[i]
    const actualObj = actualTableData[i]

    for (const key in actualObj) {
      if (
        !keysToIgnore.some(ignoreKey => key.startsWith(ignoreKey)) &&
        actualObj[key] !== null &&
        (initialObj[key] === undefined || initialObj[key] !== actualObj[key])
      ) {
        differences.push({
          value: actualObj[key],
          columnName: key,
          rowKey: i,
          rowData: actualObj,
          operation: determineOperation(initialObj[key], actualObj[key]),
        })
      }
    }
  }

  const oldDiferences = usePrevious(differences)

  if (differences.length > 0 && oldDiferences !== differences) {
    return { differences, actualTableData }
  }

  return { actualTableData }
}

export const useHasChanged = (val: OptRow[]): boolean => {
  const prevVal = usePrevious(val)
  return prevVal !== val
}
```

Please, can anybody give me a hint how can I achieve this?